# Compile loop after data return

Tags: php, laravel, lumen

I went to build an API using Lumen. i tryed to get data with a condition, 
   it's successfully return my data. My code is:

```
$speeches = Speech::where('is_requested', 0)->where('is_Submited', 0)->take(25)->get();
return response()->json(['status'=> 'Success', 'data' => $speeches], 200);
```

But i went when it's return my data, some field will update automicatly.

```
$speeches = Speech::where('is_requested', 0)->where('is_Submited', 0)->take(25)->get();

    // return response()->json(['status'=> 'Success', 'data' => $speeches], 200);

    foreach($speeches as $speechreq){

        $speechreq->update([
            'user_id'       =>  Auth::user()->id,
            'is_requested'  =>  1,
        ]);
        return response()->json(['status'=> 'Success', 'data' => $speechreq], 200);
```

it returns only one data with the update. but I need 25 data. If I write my code like

```
$speeches = Speech::where('is_requested', 0)->where('is_Submited', 0)->take(25)->get();

    return response()->json(['status'=> 'Success', 'data' => $speeches], 200);

    foreach($speeches as $speechreq){

        $speechreq->update([
            'user_id'       =>  Auth::user()->id,
            'is_requested'  =>  1,
        ]);
        // return response()->json(['status'=> 'Success', 'data' => $speechreq], 200);

    }
```

it returns me 25 data but foreach loop doesn't work. So can anyone help me, please...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Return this line `after` foreach loop.

```
return response()->json(['status'=> 'Success', 'data' => $speeches], 200);
```

Comment: welcome and don't forget to accept it as it may help others